# Magento 2: Where do Third Party Modules Go?

Tags: module, magento2

I just installed the first official release of Magento 2.  I was surprised to find that the `app/code` folder was gone

```
app/code
```

This was for both the version downloaded from the website **and** the version installed via composer.  Also, when I tried to manually create the `app/code` folder, and then do a `php bin/magento module:enable Pulsestorm_MyModule` to enable a sample module, I got the following error

```
 Unknown module(s): 'Pulsestorm_MyModule'
```

Where are third party modules supposed to live?  If the answer is "a source repository and installed via composer", how does a module developer need to structure their modules to live in a Magento 2 repository?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Preferably 3PLs will live in the vendor directory along with everything else. However… :) We all know there is typically custom code written for almost every custom site-build out there, and this IMO belongs in app/code/ still. Yes, you can still run a module from app/code.

All modules, regardless of location, should have a `composer.json` and a `registration.php` file which are used to get the module into the system. You also need the `etc/modules.xml` file. This is, technically, all it takes to register a module:

```
$ tree app/code/Alger/
app/code/Alger/
└── Skeleton
    ├── composer.json
    ├── etc
    │   └── module.xml
    └── registration.php

2 directories, 3 files
```

To get the module up and running, you need to run `setup:upgrade` and then `cache:flush` for the system to both recognize and load your new component:

```
$ bin/magento module:enable Foo_Bar
$ bin/magento setup:upgrade -q && bin/magento cache:flush -q
```

**Update:** Two methods to install module from public GitHub repo: https://gist.github.com/davidalger/77761f13d9752b117f35

Comment: I haven't needed to module:enable unless I previously disabled it. Is there a parameter you can set to install the extension disabled?

Comment: @Eirik If you're installing from repo via composer, it's done by composer. If you simply place these files there, that's when you need to enable it. At least I'm pretty sure that's what I found right after the GA as I was polishing up slides for a talk here at #phpworld :)

Comment: thanks much haven't pushed to repo yet as I was working locally. Great information.

Answer (score 6):

Alan, they still go in `app/code`. Make sure you have a `registration.php` in the modulename folder containing the following:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Namespace_Modulename',
    __DIR__
);
```

Then run:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Just tested on fresh Magento 2 CE release and works properly.

Comment: Thank you @Eirik, that was indeed it.  It wasn't clear if registration.php was something that slipped in that shouldn't have, or something that would make the final release. Pretty clear now :)