# Magento 2 where is app/code/magento pool

Tags: magento2

In the RC candidates and the CE available via GitHud app/code/magento pool is included. In the distro from magento's website the pool is missing, where is the pool stored? I ask because I am getting messages saying that the Massgenerator does not exist:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:72:"Class Magento\Salesrule\Model\Coupon\MassgeneratorFactory does not exist";i:1;s:13600:"#0 /chroot/home/html/mag2a/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(44):
```

However the exact same code run on the CE distro containing the code/magento pool handles the code just fine.

Comment: Take a look at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91012/magento-2-where-do-third-party-modules-go ... did you run `bin/magento setup:upgrade -q && bin/magento cache:flush -q` in magento root dir?

Comment: Yes and the file is in place inside the vendor/magento folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> there are two approaches of installing Magento:
>   1. from Git repository. Then all modules are in app/code, so contributors can work with them as a regular GitHub repo
>   2. via Composer. Then all core modules will be in vendor and custom modules can be created under app/code and stored under project's Git repository. The zip archive is based on this approach, just everything is already downloaded and packed in one zip
>   Source for the files is the same.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2401#issuecomment-157894163

Comment: The class existed inside the vendor/magento folder. I ended up having to make my own model using the Massgenerator and then call that. I'm not sure why I couldn't create the factory based on the core magento class.

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2 RC/CE, it only have class `Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon\Massgenerator`, can you declare it your custom module. You should disable your module and run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` in location directory install magento2