# Magento2 : How to use 3party library files in custom module

Tags: magento2

require  BP . '/var/vendor_name/geoip/geoip.inc'; to include file in class.

$data_inc =   BP . '/var/vendor_name/geoip/data/geoip.dat';

Comment: Please refer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100766/how-to-include-3rd-party-library-in-magento-2-like-php-xlsx-library
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133387/how-to-integrate-third-party-library-in-magento-2-extension
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96690/including-generated-3rd-party-php-library-in-magento2
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91012/magento-2-where-do-third-party-modules-go